# Blender model looks different in Unity

Tags: modeling, mesh

My model looks like this in Blender.
[image: blender model]

It look different in Unity.
[image: unity model]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like lighting to me, the cube shadow indicates the light is shining straight down. Try adding another light in front of the model or rotating the direction so that it points toward the front of your model. Although I think you also have to manually select the object materials in unity after importing.

Comment: thanks that answer solved my problem now i have got another problem, http://oi65.tinypic.com/23h3h1j.jpg - http://oi68.tinypic.com/2pzaeyo.jpg now how can i fix this ?

Comment: Ask another question with details of what you want help with.